# Use CSS to make clicked thumbnail display full size

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have three thumbnails displayed on the side of a page.

When clicked, the full size image needs to be displayed in the middle of the page with text underneath it.  The thumbnails need to increase in size slightly on `mouseover` as well which I already have coded by.
My main problem is getting the full size image to display though.

Here's what I have:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homework 3, CSS Styles</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
    img:hover
       {
        transform: scale(1.250,1.250);
                padding:5px;
       }
    #right
       {
       position:absolute;
       top:50px;
       right:100px;
       left:250px;
           bottom:200px;
           } 

    </style>
    <script>
    function changeSize(id)
    {
    var mainImage=document.getElementById("mainImage");
    var someImage=document.getElementById(id);
    mainImage.src=someImage.src;
    }
    </script>

    </head>   
    <body>    
        <div align="center"><img id="mainImage" style="max-width:auto; max-height:auto" align="middle" src="blank.jpg" 
alt="blank"/></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span style="cursor:pointer"><img style="max-width:70px; max-height:70px" id="cluster" src="cluster1.png" 
alt="cluster" onClick="changeSize(id)"/></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span style="cursor:pointer"><img style="max-width:70px; max-height:70px" id="gas" 
src="gas1.png" alt="gas" onClick="changeSize(id)"/></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span style="cursor:pointer"><img style="max-width:70px; max-height:70px" 
id="launch" src="launch1.jpg" alt="launch" onClick="changeSize(id)"/></span></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure it's the best way to do so, so suggestions are appreciated there.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for a [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: should be able to use similar code to your :hover for :active (becomes active when clicked) `img:active
       {
        transform: scale(1.50,1.50);
                padding:5px;
       }` with some absolute properties etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you want to do, but you should wrap your script into onload handler. Otherwise you will not get references to the DOM elements. For example:

```
var boot = function() {
    var main=document.getElementById("mainImage");
    var someImage=document.getElementById("someImage");
    main.src=someImage.src;
}
var changeSize = function() {

}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', boot, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', boot);
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  So I have three thumbnails on the left of the page that are displayed on load.  When a user click an image, it shows the full size image in the middle of the page with some text under it and keeps the three thumbnails on the left.